# BERT with 256 hidden embeddings

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, bert-language-model

I am trying to use BERT to get word embeddings from different data sets for my NLP task. I have used the 'bert_base_uncased' with 768 word embeddings but it runs out of memory. The versions with 256 word embeddings has been released? Or is there any way that I can compress the 768 hidden embeddins?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about 256 word embeddings versions for BERT, but I do know that the newer [ALBERT](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/albert.html) uses a lot less memory compared to BERT. Also, if you are constantly facing OOM issues you can try looking at 16-bit precision training or mixed-precision training. This works well with the newer RTX cards (and some others, but not the older GPUs)

Nvidia has a [library](https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex) for it but it's not very beginner friendly, or you could also consider using [Pytorch Lightning](https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning) for converting your model to 16-bit.

Comment: Thank you for your help! 
There has been released a version of BERT for 256 at https://huggingface.co/google/bert_uncased_L-12_H-256_A-4 (for future readers)